# Linking SQL Server view into Access db: performance question

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

When you attach a SQL Server view as an MS Access linked table, you are asked for a unique identifier. During recent trials, I noticed that on several occasion, NOT defining the unique identifier has the effect that the linked table opens much more quickly (you don't need a stopwatch, you can really SEE it).

So I am asking the experts if there is an explanation to this, and what is the rule: define or not define an primary key for the attached view ?

My comparisons where made on the same machine, same Access 2007 db, same views, same driver (SQL Server 10), same SQL Server 2008 server.
For my case, I don't need to update the linked tables (which are SQL views).

Comment: This is a real performance trick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access only needs a unique identifier to be able to perform updates.  If you don't define the unique identifier (and you don't need to), it isn't keeping track of them, so I guess it's faster.  I'm not sure why the difference is so noticeable.  How wide (columns and bytes) was the unique identifier you were picking on the slow version?

Comment: ID are small, like 10 char, and the data set around 15000 records. The server is powerfull and not busy. Next time I will try looking at processor usage on the client machine.

Comment: The performance difference might have something to do with it being able to use a more performance locking strategy since it knows the data will be read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your results on my test machine, and even ran profiler to see if I could figure it out. I connected to a view twice, once with a unique identifer specified and one without.  Same results as you.

Profile was not very illuminating; for the UNindexed view, it was a standard SELECT columnList FROM view.  For the Indexed view, it only specified the key column (even though the results clearly show all columns).

The only thing that I can think of is that since you are specifying a unique key in Access, the data set must be completely pulled into memory in order for Access to associate the key column on the server with the local index.  If there's no local index, then there's no need for that association to occur.

Comment: I would expect Jet to pull metadata about the index and not much else. It certainly wouldn't need to pull the whole table, and likely not even the whole PK index.

Comment: Perhaps; what confused me is that even though I saw data in the linked table display in Access, the query that was being executed on the Indexed version was only SELECTing the indexed column.  Where did the rest of the data come from?

Comment: Glad to see you found the sam thing. My findings here just due to a noticable delay when manually opening the table (several times).  
I wonder if Access is building a local unique index upon opening ?

Comment: Stuart: for the "rest of the data" you mention: maybe there is an option similar to Access "output all fields" ? (I am not a Sql Server expert).